# Why do I need to asynchronously return data when dealing a web API?

Tags: ios, networking

I'm learning how to parse JSON from web APIs. I have read that I need to asynchronously return my parsed data from the API for my application, as opposed to synchronously. I'm not sure why it has to be asynchronously. I know it has something to do with threading, but that doesn't clarify it for me.

Why do network requests have to be performed asynchronously?

Comment: Do you have code specific to this question? Update your question with relevant code. It will be much easier to explain.

Comment: Short story: The installation of an OS update is synchronous. Do you like that you can't use your computer / iPhone during the update? In a smaller dimension loading data  synchronously is quite similar.

Comment: Wasn't trying to change what the post was about, @Rob; thanks for phrasing it better!

Comment: Because _synchronously_ would mean that absolutely nothing can be done in your app until the network response is returned: no activity indicator, no progress bar, no touch events, nothing. Doing things asynchronously let you actually do things.

Comment: this is too broad, and you need to construct a question more specific to a problem

Comment: Your question is still not well constructed. Lay out the problem before the sharing the code. Beyond the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advice, you also need to start by stating the question in a way that focuses on what gap remains _after_ your research. Then describe your strategy thus far, code setup + conditions, and the errors/issues. Also state 'obvious' context that you already know, so that people understand what you have tried. See also [1](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Code is not a strict requirement [for questions that are not about debugging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/603977).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you should to do this asynchonously has nothing to do with the nature of the response (JSON or otherwise). It’s just that you’re requesting data from an API on a remote server and you don’t know how long it will take (subject to the nature of the network the device is on, how busy the web server is, etc.).

Bottom line, any task that takes more than a few milliseconds should generally be performed asynchronously to ensure a responsive UI, and this API call will take much more time than that.

Answer (score 1):

**Analogy time**

Imagine that you're employed in the information booth of a train station to manually update a board with trains' statuses. You read off an old-fashioned ticker tape and move models of the trains around so that passengers can see what's going on. You also answer questions about schedules and such directly, when passengers ask you.

You realize that for one particular portion of the board, some information is missing from your tape. Your colleague has the info, but she isn't in the station. So you leave the board, go over to the phone, and call her. You dial, and wait for her to pick up, and then explain what you need. She doesn't have what you need immediately to hand, so she asks you to wait a moment while she gets it.

Meanwhile, the tape doesn't stop. Information about trains continues to come in. but because you're sitting there on the phone waiting, you're not doing anything with it. The people who are watching the board get frustrated, and the people who have questions for you can't ask them either.

Finally, your colleage comes back and gives you what you asked for. You thank her and return to the board. You realize the board is in very bad shape, not reflecting the current state of the world at all. And the passengers with questions have stormed out and left you a one-star review on the App, I mean Train, Store.

Next day, the same situation comes up. You need information you don't have. Instead of stepping away from the board for several minutes, you quickly fire off a text message, and get right back to talking to passengers and moving things around on the board.

In about the same amount of time that you spent waiting on the phone yesterday, you get a text back from your colleague with the information. You incorporate it into your workflow, and nobody even notices that you spend a couple of seconds reading from your phone instead of the ticker tape. Victory!

---

The first day, you made a synchronous network request. You initiated a conversation with a remote service and waited until you got the response. When that happened, your UI was locked up, neither taking input from the user nor refreshing its own state.

The second day, you made an asynchronous request. You kept working normally until the response came back, allowing you to continue with all your other tasks.